# Reload layer from server

Tags: openlayers

I use openlayer 2 in my project.

At some point I need to reload specific layer on the client using ajax call.

here is my layer example:

[image]

As you can see above layer contains URL and params of the layers(Layers ID).

My question is what is best way to reload layers from the server?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30683) on the sibling forum GIS.stackexchange.com that tells you how to refresh a WMS layer (doing the Ajax call you want)

For your WMS, you should do

```
your_wms.redraw(true);
```

`redraw` is a method inherited from [OpenLayers.Layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.redraw)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20268788)

Comment: Done the change although I consider it's duplicated. I wished I could mark as duplicated on all stackexchange forums. It's a bother to refer to other stackexchange posts (the worst is when people ask the same question on 2 or more forums of the network...)